# Webmaster Tools sitemap submission

Tags: google-search-console

Can anyone tell me how to add a site map in Google Webmaster Tools?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the [Sitemaps tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/sitemap-list) (also under Crawl → Sitemaps) and click "Add/Test Sitemap", enter the relative URL to a sitemap for that property and choose Submit.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add this Sitemap to your Webmaster Tools: /sitemap_index.xml If you choose a "Sub-Sitemap" not all of your sites will be indexed.